# SharePoint - 80 : Error: The web.config is invalid on this IIS Web Site:

Tags: sharepoint-server, deployment, iis, web-config, gac

I tried to deploy a `.wsp` solution to my SP farm.

But I met the following error:

> Last Operation Result:    Some of the files failed to copy during
>   deployment of the solution.
>
> Last Operation Details:   V-SERVER1U :
>   http://v-server1u/ : SharePoint - 80 : Error: The web.config is invalid
>   on this IIS Web Site: D:\InetPub\wss\VirtualDirectories\80\web.config.

There is another suggested solution as follows, but I am unable to locate the service in my server.

> In Central Administration-> Operation-> Services on Server, please
>   stop the Windows SharePoint Services Web Application service,
>   SharePoint will remove the sites in IIS. And then start the Windows
>   SharePoint Services Web Application service again, SharePoint will
>   recreate the sites in IIS based on information stored in configuration
>   database.

I also tried to implement `-Force` in SP Management Shell deployment command, but met the following error too:

> Install-SPSolution : This solution contains resources scoped for a Web
>   application and must be deployed to one or more Web applications.

I have no other possible solutions to fix this. May I know how can I resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

The service name in your post is “Microsoft SharePoint Foundation Web Application”. You could stop and re-start the service “Microsoft SharePoint Foundation Web Application” in Services on Server.

[image]

To troubleshoot the issue, you could re-deploy the .wsp solution in the site.